# Retried waiting for GCLocker too often allocating 12488753 words

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I see the follow output on my Java console. What this means? Why it occur?

```
[477.615s][warning][gc,alloc] mythreadname: Retried waiting for GCLocker too often allocating 12488753 words
[519.628s][warning][gc,alloc] mythreadname: Retried waiting for GCLocker too often allocating 12488753 words
```

Comment: Seems that there are a problem not yet resolved https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8192647

Comment: By no means am I an expert at this, however I'm having to solve the same problem (for Logstash specifically). I have come across these two links which seem informative:

https://tech.clevertap.com/demystifying-g1-gc-gclocker-jni-critical-and-fake-oom-exceptions/

and

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/gclocker-too-often-allocating-256-words/323769/2

(The latter references the former.)